# Compare one real number to one complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

I understand that complex numbers can be neither ordered nor compared by 'size', but if mapped one for one by a transformation, then they can be. Latter point aside, can I say that $2-xi < 2 < 2+xi$?

Thanks

Comment: See complex numbers as vectors  .Can you say :$\vec a> \vec b$?

Comment: Yip duplicate will read other post please delete and reduce my reputation to -2i mu ha ha ha

Comment: Actually. Its not really the same. In the other post there is ever only talk of a zero imaginary part which has no effect on comparisons because real numbers are in effect the only things being compared. My question says is 3+3i > 2 ?

Comment: You could define that $x+iy \leq x'+iy'$ iff $x \leq x'$. This relation is reflexive and transitive but not antisymmetric. We also get the following implications: (1) for all complex $a,b,z$ it holds that $a \leq b \Rightarrow a+z \leq b+z$, and (2) for all complex $a,b$ and all non-negative reals $x$ it holds that $a \leq b \Rightarrow ax \leq bx$. However you can't generalize Theorem 2 by allowing $x$ to be complex. Could be an interesting idea, but I'm not sure either way. Maybe toy with it a bit and see if any major problems crop up.